# Is there any advantage with RIO of IOCP over events?

Tags: sockets, winapi

RIO here stands for the Windows8 'Registered I/O' Networking extensions. From looking at example code, it seems that regardless of whether you are using RIONotify with events or IO Completion Ports, you basically end up writing the same loop, and would have nearly identical performance characteristics. The loop body is:

```
RIONotify() [event or IOCP]
Wait [on the event, or using GetQueuedCompletionStatus()]
RIODequeueCompletion()
// Process the dequeued events
```

Basically it seems like the usage of IO Completion Port is providing no additional functionality over 'event' notify/waiting, since the actual queue of messages is done with RIODequeueCompletion. So it doesn't matter whether you use events, or IOCP. My question is, am I overlooking any interesting or important difference between the models?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using RIO with IOCP you could scale across multiple threads by calling RIODequeueCompletion() to dequeue multiple completions at a time, then immediately calling RIONotify() to allow more notifications and then letting your thread process the completions that you retrieved with RIODequeueCompletion(). If there are more completions available another of your threads will become active and can do the same thing. This may or may not give you improved performance over a single threaded polling loop.

I have some example code for this [here](http://www.serverframework.com/asynchronousevents/2012/03/windows-8-registered-io---multi-threaded-rio-iocp-udp-example-server.html), and some thoughts on the relative performance of various RIO designs and 'standard' UDP server designs [here](http://www.serverframework.com/asynchronousevents/2012/08/windows-8server-2012-registered-io-performance---take-2.html).

Comment: Thanks! I had read your articles, and this additional explanation is appreciated. But in principle one could still scale across multiple receive threads *without* IOCP manually by manually distributing job of calling RIODequeue completion across some workers threads, right? Is IOCP more about making that convenient than performant?

Comment: You could do it manually, but why bother? IOCP would be more performant and obvious. Anything else would likely require that you wake up threads "prematurely" to poll for completions.

Answer (score 5):

RIO is about registering buffers with the kernel to save overhead and about more efficient queue management. It's not a fundamental shift. Just [a lot less overhead](http://www.serverframework.com/asynchronousevents/2012/08/windows-8server-2012-registered-io-performance---take-2.html).

IOCP is not about increasing the performance of individual actions. It is about using less threads and about context switching less. RIO takes it a little further.